# Android getAdapterPosition returns always getItemCount

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to develop a recyclerview, that needs to load new elements, as the user scrolls down (a recycler for news feed). The problem is that with any method I try, my adapter sees that the visible items from recycler are same as getItemCount. One method I tried was override following class in adapter:

```
@Override
public void onViewAttachedToWindow(@NonNull ViewHolder holder) {
    super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder);
    if((getItemCount() -1) == holder.getAdapterPosition()){
        Log.e("TAGNews", "List Done!");
    }
}
```

or, another mehthod implemented in my fragment:

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                int visibleItemCount = manager.getChildCount();
                int totalItemCount = manager.getItemCount();
                int firstVisibleItem = manager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();



                if (loading) {
                    if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                        loading = false;
                        previousTotal = totalItemCount;
                    }
                }
                if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount)
                        <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                    // End has been reached

                    Log.e("News!", "end called");

                    loadMoreNews();

                    loading = true;
                }
            }
        });
```

But always, my messages for debug, that must trigger by the end of the recycler, are triggered when recycler opens.
[Here's how my recycler looks for the first time it's opened, without any scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uAR3.jpg)

I load from 3 to 10 items from my backend and news have similar height.

Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 0):

Please change your second code to this:

```
int lastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition;
recycler.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx,    int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            lastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) binding.recycler.getLayoutManager()).findLastVisibleItemPosition();
            if (dy > 5)
                if (lastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition == models.size() - 1) {
                  loadMoreData();
                }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, but the problem is other. The news feed needs pagination, so when I make a backend call, I receive let's say n number of news for the desired page, and pass it to recycler. The getItemCount works fine, as you say, but why my adapter always says the the first element is the last one that's render on the screen. Basicly I want to call the method that makes request for a new page when user reaches the last news.

Comment: I edit my answer based on your comment, please check it again and if it help you, confirm it. thanks